# htaccess on 1 query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder, which is inside a subdomain folder

The Folder is

```
/home/user1/public_html/subdomain/user/transfer
```

My subdomain folder is

```
/home/user1/public_html/subdomain/
```

There this folder call user in it, and transfer is inside user.

So the hierarchy is

```
subdomain > user > transfer
```

and inside transfer folder there are 2 files

```
index.php and also a .htaccess
```

My .htaccess rule is as followed:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^transfer/(.*) /transfer/index.php-action=$1 [R=302,L]
```

I trying to access the page by

```
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/cash
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/credit
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/AnyWord
```

whereby it will load the content of

```
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=cash
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=credit
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=AnyWord
```

But it give me an error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /user/transfer/cash was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What should I do to handle this and make my .htaccess rewrite works.

I can access

```
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=cash
```

I just want rewrite the url to something like

```
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/cash
```

And it will load the content of

```
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/user/transfer/index.php?action=cash
```

Comment: How about `RewriteRule ^/user/transfer/(.*) /transfer/index.php-action=$1 [R=302,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/user/transfer/.htaccess` you need to have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/transfer/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: sorry was not able to mark earlier on, I just mark it. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

Firstly make sure your subdomain is working correctly, forget the htaccess redirect and just put a test.html file with "Hello World" in it to make sure its working correctly.

Secondly, bring your .htaccess file back up to your root directory and your rewrite rule has a typo where you have a - instead of a ? It should read.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^transfer/(.*) /user/transfer/index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

You also have it setup as a redirect. I've taken this part out too, so your URL is still "masked".